# How Chinese character trigger VsCode completions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I wrote a VsCode extension And I want to trigger that when I input a Chinese character. So is there a better way to do this than list all Chinese character?

Following shows the API I used.

```
registerCompletionItemProvider(selector: DocumentSelector, provider: CompletionItemProvider, ...triggerCharacters: string[]): Disposable;
```